# Convert boto3.resource(...) to boto3.client?

Tags: python, boto3

I found the following code in a class.

```
self.s3client = boto3.client("s3")
self.s3client.put_object(...)
```

And later the following code in the same class,

```
self.s3object = boto3.resource("s3")
obj = self.s3object.Object(BUCKET_NAME, LAST_DOWNLOADED_ID_KEY)  # use boto3.client?
```

Is it possible to convert the later one to use `boto3.client` so instance variable `self.s3object` can be removed?

Comment: Yes, the resources are just convenience functions, everything can be done through the lower level client api.